# Use local docker image having mysql with minikube

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, linux-mint, minikube

On my laptop, I have Linux Mint OS. Details as below:

```
Mint version 19, 
Code name : Tara,
PackageBase : Ubuntu Bionic
Cinnamon (64-bit)
```

1. I have webservice written using spring boot and mysql.
2. It works fine locally.- verified and tested...
   Using dockerfile I have created docker image. 
   From the directory of Dockerfile ran command- `docker build . -t users-mysql-docker`

Run the Docker image (users-mysql-docker) created.
`docker run -p 8086:8086 --name users-mysql-app --link mysql-standalone:mysql -d users-mysql-docker`  (In this command we sort of link our own image with standalone mysql.)

I already have mysql image in docker and container mysql-standalone.

3. I started minikube and checked pods and deployments

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~$ pwd
> /home/sj
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ minikube start
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get pods
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get deployments
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
> ```

Now when I check docker images, looks like as the [README](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon) describes, it reuses the Docker daemon from Minikube with `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

4. As per [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) link I did setup mysql on minikube.
   with that what I see in pods, deployments and services

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get pods
> NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
> mysql-6c57cd4d76-gxb7g       1/1     Running   1          9d
>
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get deployments
> NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
> mysql       1         1         1            1           8d
>
> xxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get services
> NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
> kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          9d
> mysql        ClusterIP      None             <none>        3306/TCP         8d
> ```

5. Now I want to deploy the same webservice from step# 1 to kubernetes(minikube).
   I went to directory where I have dockerfile and ran build command as below:

> xxxxxxxxx:/directory$
>   docker build . -t users-mysql-kube:V1

Verified if I can see image in deamon docker within minikube.

```
xxxxxxxxxx:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
users-mysql-kube                           V1                  53152583b2b8        2 seconds ago       652MB
openjdk                                    8                   81f83aac57d6        5 weeks ago         624MB
mysql                                      5.7                 563a026a1511        5 weeks ago         372MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                         1.2.2               367cdc8433a4        6 weeks ago         39.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      v1.10.0             0dab2435c100        7 weeks ago         122MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.10.0             bfc21aadc7d3        6 months ago        97MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.10.0             af20925d51a3        6 months ago        225MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.10.0             704ba848e69a        6 months ago        50.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.10.0             ad86dbed1555        6 months ago        148MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64                      3.1.12              52920ad46f5b        7 months ago        193MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-addon-manager              v8.6                9c16409588eb        7 months ago        78.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     1.14.8              c2ce1ffb51ed        9 months ago        41MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           1.14.8              6f7f2dc7fab5        9 months ago        42.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          1.14.8              80cc5ea4b547        9 months ago        50.5MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        9 months ago        742kB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner    v1.8.1              4689081edb10        11 months ago       80.8MB
```

**Below steps I tried just as TESTING PURPOSE. I may be wrong. Please provide your suggestions on that**

6. As mentioned in step# 2 the way I run docker image and link it to mysql, **how do we run created image in step# 5 inside minikube and link it to deployed mysql**?
   Is it something like:

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl run umk-01 --image=users-mysql-kube:V1 --image-pull-policy=Never
> ```

7. after image is deployed, **how to expose it**?
   should I do something like:

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl expose deployment umk-01 --type=NodePort --port=8086
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get services
> NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
> kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          9d
> mysql        ClusterIP      None             <none>        3306/TCP         8d
> umk-01       NodePort       10.100.105.58    <none>        8086:30004/TCP   6s
> ```

8. I have tried step 6 and 7 and then tried below command but it didn't work.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ minikube service umk-01 --url
> Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
> ```

It means something is wrong there in step#6 and 7 . 
Can someone help with that?

Comment: Check what is the address of your minikube using `minikube ip`. Locate the nodeport used by service `kubectl get svc umk-01`. And finally test it with `curl MINIKUBE_IP:NODE_PORT`

Comment: `xxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get svc umk-01` gave port  8086:32581/TCP   and `xxxxxxxxxx:~$ minikube ip ` gave 192.168.99.100` and then tried to test `xxxxxxxxxx:~$ curl 192.168.99.100:32581` this gives error- 
_curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 32581: Connection refused_

Comment: You can try connecting to your pod using `kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -- /bin/bash` and checking it it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you get a service URL for nodeport service with Minikube. You can directly access the service on Minikube IP & port 30004. Just make sure you dont have firewall blocking the port.

Comment: I am doing this on local so I am sure there is no firewall issue. However, if you go thru my post description step 6 and 7 looks incorrect. I guess if that is rectified it should work. Can you look thru that and provide your thought?